# Inverse squares of binomials as moments of a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

Does anyone know of a probability distribution, parametrized by $M$, having $\binom{M+n-1}{n}^{-2}$ as its moments? i.e. some non-negative function $f_M(x)$ on some interval $(a,b)$ such that
$$ \mu_n=\int_a^b x^n f_M(x)dx=\frac{1}{\binom{M+n-1}{n}^{2}}$$

I have found these moments by an indirect route, and now I would like to know the associated distribution. One way to proceed would be to compute the moment generating function $g(y)=\sum_n \frac{1}{n!}\mu_n y^n$, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: The MGF is the hypergeometric function

$$ g(y) = {}_2F_2([1,1],[M,M],y) $$

Answer (score 1):

The moment generating function $g(y)$ is related to the probability density $f_M(x)$ by 
$$ f_M(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iyt}g(iy)dy$$

Using the integral representation of the hypergeometric function $_2F_2$ mentioned by Robert Israel, I got
$$f_M(x)=(M-1)^2\int_x^1\frac{dt}{t}\left[(1-t)\left(1-\frac{x}{t}\right)\right]^{M-2}.$$
A more explicit form is out of reach, I guess.

The moments of this function in the interval $(0,1)$ are precisely ${M+n-1\choose n} ^{-2}$.